# How to separate several inputs on a jtextfield

Tags: java

I am doing a Wage Calculator that will calculate a worker's salary according to their position as the boss, commission worker and such but i need it to accept 5 inputs each textfield for the First name, Last name, and salary. How do i seperate each inputs from each textfields?

Example :
First Name: Boss, Boss, Boss, Boss, Boss
Last Name:  A, B, C, D, E
Salary:     1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Output:
Boss A earned 1
Boss B earned 2
Boss C earned 3
Boss D earned 4
Boss E earned 5

Here's a part  of my code, this can only print 1 input

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //BOSS
    if (e.getSource() == fldSalary)
    {
        String first = fldFirst.getText();
        String last = fldLast.getText();
        double salary = Double.parseDouble(fldSalary.getText());


        Boss boss = new Boss(first,last,salary);

        employee = boss;
        output = employee.toString() + " earned Php" + precision2.format(employee.earnings()) + "\n \n" ;
        area.append(output);
    }  
}
```

Comment: use split function to get each one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) function

```
String last= fldLast.getText();  // last=" A, B, C, D, E";
String[] parts = last.split(", ");
String part1 = parts[0]; // A
String part2 = parts[1]; // B
String part3 = parts[2]; // C
String part4 = parts[3]; // D
String part5 = parts[4]; // E
```

Same for `first`  and `salary` (Salary should be string, then parse each one to double)

Comment: Okay, Do i print them one by one? How?